# Create array of array Schema using mongoose for NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I want to create a DB Schema to store the data as below

```
{
    name : "xyz",
    admin : "admin",
    expense : [ 
                jan: [{expenseObject},{expenseObject}], 
                feb: [[{expenseObject},{expenseObject}]
              ]
}
```

Expense Object

```
var expenseSchema = new Schema({
    particular : String,
    date : {type : Date, default: Date.now},
    paid_by : String,
    amount : Number
});
```

Can someone help me create a schema for the same.

Any suggestions for a better Schema for the same concept are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Sub Docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html)

```
var parentSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  admin: { type: String },
  expense: [expenseSchema]
});
```

Or, if you need the expenseObjects to be stored in a seperate collection you can use [refs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html), where Expense would be the name of another model

```
var parentSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String },
  admin: { type: String },
  expense: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Expense' }],
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var expenseSchema = new Schema({
  particular : String,
  date : {type : Date, default: Date.now},
  paid_by : String,
  amount : Number
});

// your schema
var mySchema = new Schema({
   name : {type: String, trim: true},
   admin : {type: String, trim: true},
   expense: [expenseSchema]
});
```

--- UPDATE:

With this update now `expense` is an array of `expenseSchema` without any categorisation of month. Then if you want to get all expenses in a particular month you can simply do an aggregation like this:

```
db.users.aggregate(
  [
   // this match is for search the user
   { $match: { name: "<ADMIN NAME>"} },
   // this unwind all expenses of the user selected before
   { $unwind: "$expense" },
   // this project the month number with the expense
   {
     $project: {
      expense: 1, 
      month: {$month: '$expense.date'}
    }
   },
   // this search all the expenses in a particular month (of the user selected before)
   { $match: { month: 8 } },
   // this is optional, it's for group the result by _id of the user
   //(es {_id:.., expenses: [{}, {}, ...]}. Otherwise the result is a list of expense
   {
    $group: {
      _id:"$month",
      expenses: { $addToSet: "$expense"}
    }
  }
 ]);
```

Comment: can I add the jan, feb, etc through the code rather than hardcoding it in the Schema? Like I mean to say add the month array only when required

Comment: nope. with this solution you can only hardcode all months. You cannot define a model that in future change dynamically (adding a month for example). You can change your structure or hardcode all months and if there aren't expense the array it's empty. Check [this](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1867)

Comment: Is there a better way of doing this? I need to store expense of each month for this document. and the expenses is an object as mentioned in the question. Would be great if you could provide some better idea of doing the same.

Comment: yes of course but i don't understand why you want have the month name as a key of an array. You can simply have `expenses` as array of expense and every expense have the month (or simply the date). If you want all the expenses in a particular month you should do a good query.

Comment: I felt it's better to categorize the expenses by month. However am new to NoSQL. So you think it's better to do query for month rather than grouping it as array? Thanks :)